# problema con mis botones dinamicos de una tabla, mi funcion reacciona despues de varios clicks

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Tengo problemas con mi evento addEventListenner, cuando doy click a un boton la funcion se retrasa y despues de varios clicks funciona

Ya inicialice mi base de datos en firebase, estoy codificando en javascript, solo adjunto como saco los datos de firebase, mi fila donde al final estan mi boton y la funcion cuando le daoy click a los botones

```
getDocs(safety_users)
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const data = doc.data();
      const id = doc.id;
      const employee = data.employee;
      const nombre = data.name;
      const surnames = data.surnames;
      const correo = data.email;
      const number = data.number;
      const cargo = data.position

      console.log("id:", id);
      console.log("Nombre:", nombre, surnames);
      console.log("num. Empleado:", employee);
      console.log("Correo: ", correo);
      console.log("number:", number);
      console.log("Puesto", cargo)

      //filas de la tabla
      const fila = `<tr>
      <td>${employee}</td>
      <td>${cargo}</td>
      <td>${nombre} ${surnames}</td>
      <td>${correo}</td>
      <td>${number}</td>
      <td>
      <button type="button" data-id="${id}"  id="editar" class="btn btn-outline-info" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" title="Editar"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i>
      </button>
      <button type="button" data-id="${id}" id="borrar" class="btn btn-outline-danger" title="Eliminar"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></button>
      </td>
    </tr>`;
      document.getElementById("tablaDatos").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].innerHTML += fila;
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error getting documents: ", error);
  });
  document.getElementById("tablaDatos").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    if (target.matches("#editar")) {
        console.log("editar")
    }
    if (target.matches("#borrar")) {
      console.log("borrar")
    }
});
});
```

Intento que al rpimer click cumpla su funcion cada boton y funciona aleatoriamente mi boton, avaces su aveces no